# Septic Tank backed up into the basement. What now?

Tags: basement, mold, carpet, septic, sewage

We had a flash flood over the weekend which caused the septic tank to overflow, spilling vile sewage water into my parent’s house while they were away. There was about 2 inches of water and most of it was in the laundry room and garage which both have concrete floors, but the water also leaked into the bathroom and onto a significant amount of the carpet in the bedroom and den area.

I managed to get all of the water out of the house, I’ve got industrial fans on the carpets and a dehumidifier running, I’ve thrown away all of the porous items that got soaked, and I’ve bleached the tile in the bathroom and the concrete in the other rooms. I’m planning on getting something to sanitize the carpets today and I’ll also wipe down all of the non porous items that got drenched.

I’m just wondering what steps I can take to ensure that there are no long term ramifications like mold and all that. I told my parents they should just get the carpets replaced (they’re like 18 years old anyway). Should we get a professional to come out and assess the damage? Would it be unwise to stay in the basement for too long until this gets sorted? My brother lives in the bedroom down there. I’m particularly worried about the air quality.

I appreciate any advice. This is not the first time this has happened. The last time, I don’t exactly remember what my folks did to rectify the issue but I feel like they weren’t thorough enough. That’s why I’d like to get some outside opinions.

Comment: Is there insurance?  The damage and clean up sounds like it is enough to get the insurance company involved and have professionals do extensive cleaning. The carpets and pads should be replaced. Possibly any other surface that may have soaked up pathogens.

Comment: The inside of walls can be a problem to dry.  Stud walls with drywall should probably remove the bottom foot or two of drywall.

Comment: Yup, my first thought was that "porous material" includes drywall and any insulation in the exterior walls.